# Displaying html stored in a database with the appropriate line breaks

Tags: php, html, database

I have code written in a database in several languages, html, css, php, etc.
I want it to show on my page with the appropriate line breaks. Like this:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/668127780927701032/1016459728194375780/unknown.png

So, when I display html, it executes it instead of displaying it, which is normal.
So I use htmlspecialchar, except that I can't make a line break anymore, everything is displayed on one line. And I can't **br** out of this.

How do I do that?

Comment: Call `htmlspecialchar()` first, then call `nl2br()`

Comment: For some reason, when I enter "echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($stmt['html']));" which contains "<!DOCTYPE \n html>", it shows "<!DOCTYPE \n html>" but when I enter "echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars("<!DOCTYPE \n html>"));" it shows the thing with the line break.

I'm totally lost.

Comment: Looks like `$stmt['html']` contains literal `\n`, not a newline character.

Comment: Use `str_replace('\n', '<br>')` to replace that.

Comment: Where do I put that?

Comment: Use that instead of `nl2br()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your string contains literal `\n` characters, not newlines. So you need to replace that with `<br>`.

```
echo str_replace('\n', '<br>', htmlspecialchars($stmt['html']));
```